# WMI query on virtual machine returning local info

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmi, virtual-machine, remote-access

To keep things brief, I need to manage and update a list of about 150 virtual servers. I would like to get some information about them, but for the sake of example, let's say I only want the RAM and physical processors of my virtual machine.

However, when I query the virtual server, the information returned is only information about my local machine, not the virtual one. I'm at a loss on where to go. The most help that I've gotten was from http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/.

My application is programmed in C#.NET and connstr is the string created from the following:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder stb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
stb.DataSource = lbxConnections.SelectedItem.ToString();
stb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

string connstr = stb.ToString();
```

Where lbxConnections is a list box populated with the connection info from my database of active sql servers.

The code that I'm using to query the virtual machine, after successfully connecting to it and ensuring that it's there, is as follows with

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
```

which jumps down into the following code block

```
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + connstr + "\root\virtualization");
ObjectQuery queryObj = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher vmSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manScope, queryObj);
ManagementObjectCollection vmCollection = vmSearcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject vm in vmCollection)
{
    txtPhysicalProcessors.Text = (vm["NumberOfProcessors"]).ToString();
    txtRam.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(vm.Properties["TotalPhysicalMemory"].Value) / 1073741824, 1)) + " GB";
}
```

I apologize if my question falls out of community standards, as this is my first post on StackOverflow after having all of my other questions in 4 years of software answered by past posts.

Any help or advice would be awesome. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to adjust your `ManagementScope` in order for it to work. Instead of the `connstr` you're giving now, replace it with the ip-address or the name of the VMMware instance.  (Personally I mostly used the name of the target machine) Also, in this case you'll have to escape the `\` by using a `\\`.

So far it's the first time I see a WMI query using a `SqlConnectionString`, doubt if it's even possible.

```
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\\\" + myServerName+ \\root\\virtualization");  
ObjectQuery queryObj = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher vmSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manScope, queryObj);

foreach (ManagementObject ob in vmSearcher.Get())
{
    txtPhysicalProcessors.Text = ob["NumberOfProcessors"].ToString();
    txtRam.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(ob["TotalPhysicalMemory"].ToString()) / 1073741824, 1)) + " GB";
}
```

On a side note, check out [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572), it might help in generating WMI queries in C#. Giving you the code to execute.

Comment: My connstr is generated from a query that I made that pulls out either the name or the ip of my virtual machine. The first code block I inserted into my question uses my query onto the table of virtual machine addresses and populates lbxConnections, which then uses the selected value to connect to and query WMI for virtual info.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, your connstr does not look like `"Sever=x;Initial catalog=x;username=x;password=x;"`? And just out of curiosity, does the code work if you hard-code the name or ip of the server (and set the double `\`, would you get any results that way?

Comment: It does not, after storing my admin credentials, connstr looks like "Data Source=x; Integrated Security=True", where Data Source is the ip or name of the virtual machine I'm trying to access.

Comment: I see, the thing with the managementscope is, that it probably doesn't work due to too much info inside. All the scopes I have worked with in the past come down to: `\\\\myServer\\root\\virtualization`. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but that's all you have to do to set the scope. In case you want to add credentials use the `ManagementScope` overload constructor together with the `ConnectionOptions` class

Comment: I don't store my credentials within the  ManagementScope  , I store it in a method that uses: `PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)` to `ValidateCredentials`. I truly have been in a tussle with this program.